# Count words in <pre> tag using php or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to count the words in the following statement:

```
<pre id="output" class="output">["PHP","Python"]</pre>
```

I then need to assign each word to a PHP variable via POST (Submit Button)

I don't know how to count in either PHP or JQuery when the words are within the [" "," "] tags? I have a plugin(can't edit the code) that populates the pre tag as described.

Thanks in advance

Simon

Comment: Okay. Where are you stuck? As it is, this question is too broad for SO's format. If you run into a specific problem writing the code to do this, ask about that specific problem.

Comment: Fair point. I don't know how to count in either PHP or JQuery when the words are within the [" "," "] tags? I have a plugin(can't edit the code) that populates the pre tag as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<pre id="output" class="output">["PHP","Python"]</pre>
<form method="post" target="#" id="myForm">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<textarea id="result" style="width:400px; height:200px;">
</textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
//get rid of the brackets and split the vars with the comma as a delimiter
var varsArray= $("#output").html().split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',');

//count the elements:
var total = $(varsArray).length;

$(varsArray).each(function(idx,value){
    // the each function provides id and value, you use those to create a hidden field
    // in your form and set its name using the id, and value using the value 
    $("#myForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="var'+idx+'" value='+value+'>\n\r');
});

//print the new form's content into the text area just to see what it will look like
$("#result").val($("#myForm").html());
```

here is an example for you in jsfiddle, i hope it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/AD8x9/

Comment: Thanks Banana, just what i was looking for. The complete example helped me understand. I'm still an enthusiastic beginner learner on php jquery JavaScript and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to get the content of the pre so:

Example with jQuery:

```
var contents = $("#output").html();

//now you could need to remove "[" and "]":

contents = contents.replace("[","").replace("]","");
var elements = contents.split(",");

//now you will have to check the length of "elements"

var count = elements.length;
```

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, this worked for me but unfortunately i have to give the credits to Banana as they gave me way to extract to a variable and post within a form.